# How to get the browser border to lock to a div when resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I'm looking at this [3 fixed-column CSS layout](http://www.vanseodesign.com/blog/demo/3-column-css/index.php) on http://www.vanseodesign.com.  I want to use this layout however I'd like to change the way it behaves when I resize the browser.

When the browser is open nice and wide the columns are centered nicely on the page:

[image: Columns are centered]

Then we reduce the width of the browser and it locks to the left side of the left-most column like this:

[image: Showing left column]

What I'd like to do is change the CSS (or javascript if necessary) so that the browser locks to the left side of the middle column instead when the browser becomes too narrow:

[image]

I'm not sure how to achieve this though??  Can anyone suggest how to change the code and most importantly why your solution works?

**EDIT:**

**For those reading this question:** I marked Salem Ouerdani's answer as the correct one because he was the first to answer with a solution that worked the particular way I wanted. However, it became clear that people were interpreting the question in slightly different ways.  So it is worth reading through because there are some really great answers which might suit your situation better.  Please upvote them as such.

Comment: When you say too narrow, I assume you mean narrow enough to hide one sidebar. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: When I was writing this question I didn't realise it could be interpreted so many ways.  What I was trying to say was that the 3 columns need to stay centered on the page as the browser width is reduced until the left browser border meets the left side of the center div.  The left browser border should then stay locked on the center div's left border as the browser width is reduced further.  Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Okay, then what do you want to do about the *primary sidebar*? you can either leave it accessible through scroll (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/dp7gwcn5/ or hide it http://jsfiddle.net/dp7gwcn5/2).

Comment: The primary sidebar wont actually contain any content in this instance, just a background image.  It can be hidden.  However, because the page is centered both sidebars will eventually be hidden as the browser width gets narrower.  Yet more detail that I forgot to add to the question!!

Comment: There, http://jsfiddle.net/dp7gwcn5/4/, That should do the trick :). I am updating the answer below to match your requirement. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31809733/1799502

Comment: So if I'm correct your javascript function should be the most widely supported solution so far?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, I recommend using `calc` but remember that it is fully supported only from IE10 and media queries only from IE8. So to answer your question, yes Javascript is the best way to cover most browsers **so far**. Also an additional benefit is its accuracy and control.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to modify your **container** div from this :

```css
#container { width: 960px; margin: 20px auto;}
```

to this :

```css
#container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -480px; /* half the fixed width */
}
```

---

**EDIT :**
Also you need to add this in order to lock to the left side of the center div whenever your browser size is beyond the fixed 960px :

```css
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    #container {
        left: 0;
        margin-left: -240px; /* Primary Sidebar width */
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE :** As *`@media (max-width: 480px){}`* did better solve the issue rather than *`960px`* then I'm adding the related code pen example with the final solution :  

### >> Codepen sample code

Comment: This is almost correct.  This has the effect of centering the page.  But I want the browser to lock to the *left side* of the center div as pictured above.

Comment: I see, in this case I think you will also need the media query to adjust the width, I just  updated my answer

Comment: If you change it to @media (max-width: 480px) then it works as I wanted.  Nice answer!

Answer (score 6):

### Update 2015-08-03 01:59 +0000

Reading [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668570/how-to-get-the-browser-edge-to-lock-to-a-div-when-resizing#comment51486647_31777768) on another answer about staying centered until the left edge of the centered column meets the browser edge made things much clearer.

This will keep the middle column centered until the browser is as large as the column, then it will stick to the left edge of the column.

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #container {
        margin-left:-240px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 960px) and (min-width:481px) {
    #container {
        margin-left:calc( (960px - 100%) / -2 );
    }
}
```

### Original anwser

Pure css. The values of "960" and "720" should be adjusted to account for body margin. Works under Firefox, no guarantees elsewhere. Using `calc()` for adaptive negative margin based on browser width.

```
/* fixed negative margin below 720px width */
@media (max-width: 720px) {
    #container {
        margin-left:-240px;
    }
}

/* adaptive negative margin vetween 720px and 960px width */
@media (max-width: 960px) and (min-width:721px) {
    #container {
        margin-left:calc( (960px - 100%) * -1 );
    }
}
```

### Preview

[image: screenshot-20150803-040729-004115-mod.png]

Comment: I did consider taking this approach (as you can see from my comments from CHoltzman's answer below).  However I think this would probably be a last resort.  Thanks for answering!

Comment: This is a good answer except that the different browsers seem to act differently.  None of them are centering the columns correctly.  However it does lock to the left side of the center column.  Well done.

Comment: Using cutting-edge css tends to do that. It's no wonder javascript is often used for styling.

Comment: Actually, the different browsers aren't that bad now that I look again at it.  It's just not centering correctly.

Comment: Could be conflicting margin/padding. Have you adjusted the media rules based on the body margin/padding ? Maybe it requires some offset.

Comment: Have you tried `html, body { margin:0; padding:0; }` ?

Comment: @PaulMatthews I think that last edit should do it. Reading your comments on other answers was enlightening.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make all of that abundantly clear...  Sometimes it's hard to know exactly how people will interpret the question.

Answer (score 6):

## Revised Solution (based on OP [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668570/how-to-get-the-browser-edge-to-lock-to-a-div-when-resizing?noredirect=1#comment51570449_31668570))

[Solution by @spenibus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31777706/1799502) is the best and I recommend that. The solution does not work with browsers <= IE9 (IE9 only partially supports it). If you wish to make it cross browser compatible, then I suggest using javascript to manually set the scroll.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/dp7gwcn5/4/

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width <= 960) {
            if(width <= 480) $(document).scrollLeft($('#content').offset().left);
            else $(document).scrollLeft((960-width) / 2);
        }
    });
});
```

## Old Solution

### Solution #1 (Scroll: Do not hide anything, just cling)

If you wish to keep the sidebar still accessible by scrolling but only make the browser's left edge stick to the left edge of your main content `#content`. Then manipulate the scroll

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/dp7gwcn5/. The fiddle will let you change the size of your preview window, as soon as you shrink it enough to hide the secondary sidebar the window clings to the left edge of `#content`

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ($(window).width() < 720) {
            $(document).scrollLeft($('#content').offset().left);
        }
    });
});
```

**Note**: The width 720 was given based on the widths you have set on your sidebars and conents, you can modify it to be calculated on the fly if you wish.

### Solution #2 (Static: Hide primary sidebar)

If you wish to hide the primary sidebar then simply use a media query to hide the primary sidebar when your window size is small

**Fiddle**:http://jsfiddle.net/dp7gwcn5/1/

```
@media all and (max-width:720px) {
    #primary {
        display:none;
    }

    #container {
        width:720px;
    }
}
```

### Solution #3 (Dynamic: Hide primary sidebar)

**Solution #2** is static and there is not much you can do about it, however, if you wish to compute the widths on the fly and hide the side bar, use a script

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/dp7gwcn5/2/

#### Script

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ($(window).width() < 720) $('#container').addClass('small');
        else $('#container').removeClass('small');
    });
});
```

#### CSS

```
#container.small {
    width:720px;
}

#container.small #primary {
    display:none;
}
```

### My Suggestion

My suggestion is to use **Solution #1** if you do not wish to make it mobile compatible. If you wish to make it mobile compatible I suggest using **Solution #2** with a menu button to show your primary sidebar.

**Note**: Solution #1 and Solution #3 will work on most browsers. Solution #2 will not work on browsers < IE9

Comment: Although I think the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31777611/3512867) from [Salem Ouerdani](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1868790/salem-ouerdani) is more elegant than mine, since `position` is better supported than `calc()`.

Comment: Thats true, but I prefer to avoid using `position` unless there is no other way to achieve a particular design without it. It might not cause the design to break on its own but if the page has more components then things get a bit messy with position.

Answer (score 5):

From what I can see, this template uses the margin 0 auto in the container. The way the margin is set up, it centres the "container" which contains all three columns. This means that the content is currently centred by treating each of the three columns as one big one.

This layout is also not responsive. This means that it does not adapt to larger or smaller browser sizes. It has a fixed width and height.

A simple solution is to change the pixel units to %. This will create a fluid layout that will adapt more easily to the browser size as the measurements are based on a portion of the window size instead of having a fixed size.

For example:

```
body {

width: 50%; }
```

No matter what size the browser window is, the body will only account for half the size.

If you are looking to have all three columns visible in the exact same layout or just visible in the browser without scrolling to the side no matter what device or screen size, then you need to use media queries. Media queries are css properties that let you set specific css styles for specific resolutions or screen sizes.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: purple;
    }
}
```

In my example (although very rough), the background of the body will be purple up to a small size of 600px. It will then change to blue until a size of 300px.

You can read more about media queries here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Thank-you for your detailed answer.  However I'm not sure this really answers my question.  I don't think I want a fluid layout at this stage because I have background images that need to fit together correctly.

Comment: Although possibly I could use media queries to adjust the width of the left hand column (down to 0px) depending on the width of the browser maybe?

Comment: Have you tried changing the float to orient right instead of left?

Comment: Tried setting the right hand div to float:right; but didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 5):

1 - remove the margin from your BODY CSS.

2 - wrap all of your html in a wrapper  ... all your body content

3 - Define the CSS for the wrapper:

This will hold everything together, centered on the page.

```
#conatiner{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.container {
    max-width: 960px !important;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

it will work definitely .

Answer (score 2):

```
html, body
    {
       overflow: scroll !important;
       ms-overflow-y: auto; 
       float: none !important; 
       overflow-y: auto; 
       overflow-x: visible; 
    }
```

try this in css
or in script use

```
  function enableScrolling()
        {
            document.body.scroll = "yes"; 
            document.body.overflow="hidden";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@media(max-width : 960px)
{
  #primary{width:0;}
  #content{width:66.7%}
  #secondary{width:33.3%}
  #container{width:100%}
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with media queries

At the bottom of your CSS, just add something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 960px) {

    #container {
        margin-left: -260px;
    }

}
```

When the window size becomes less than 960px, it will shift the container to the left by the width of the left column, leaving it fixed on the left side at the middle column

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Locwv54q/

EDIT:

With the addition of CSS transitions to make things smoother you can use something like this

At the bottom of your CSS add a media query:

```
@media (max-width : 960px) {

    #container {
        left: 460px;
        margin-left: -700px;
    }

}
```

Then during the definition of container earlier in the CSS, use something like this:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width:960px;
    margin-left: -480px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Of course can fiddle with the values/timings to get things exactly as you want, but this general approach works on my end

updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8L5n58jy/

EDIT2:

This should now work as intended

```
@media (max-width : 480px) {
#container {
    margin-left: -240px;
    left: 0px;
}
}

#container {
position: absolute;
width: 960px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -480px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This is the closest answer so far.  Thankyou.  As you resize the browser it feels a little bit disjointed though.  I would prefer it to be smooth if possible.

Comment: updated the answer to make the transition smooth. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Things get more complicated with the addition of transitions because we need to find another way to center the container div without using margin: auto. But if you replace the original #container with the updated, things should look identical to before despite the code change, and when you resize the container smoothly transitions to the left

Comment: I see where you're going with your update.  But I would still prefer the page to be centered automatically until it becomes small enough so that it locks to the center column.  Perhaps I could have worded my question a bit better, sorry.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but the solution I posted automatically centers everything when the page is fully wide open (i.e. if you look at the updated jsfiddle and increase the size of the preview everything should be centered). But when the window gets smaller and reaches the width of the container, everything will shift and lock to the left side of the center column. Could you clarify what you mean by centered automatically?

Comment: Basically I mean that the center div should ALWAYS be centered until the left hand side of the browser actually MEETS the left hand side of the center column.  I apologise if I didn't make that abundantly clear in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to always center the `#container` with

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform:translateX(-50%);
```

Then when it will only fit the center column and 1 column `(max-width: 720px)` you fix the position:

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {
    #container {
        left:240px;
        transition: left 2s;//make it smooth 
    }
}
```

A plus for the crazy tab resizers would be to add transition to animate the change `transition: left 2s;` (but thinking about 'normal' users it may not be necessary)

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/3h13v5j2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely read about Twitter-Bootstrap framework, bro:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h2>Left</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>Center</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h2>Right</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

would do your work, as it is RESPONSIVE. Just saying!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to create the columns and use the `col-sm-` or the `col-xs-` to pull the middle container into place?

Here is the example at the [Bootstrap Website](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping)